# Executing multiple mysql queries in consectuive mysqli_query php

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to execute these queries

```
$q1 = "INSERT INTO t1 (id,desc) VALUES (1,'desc');" <br>
$q2 = "SET @last_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();" <br>
$q3 = "INSERT INTO t2 (parentid,desc) VALUES (@last_id, 'somedesc');"<br>
```

Will this work correctly 3 mysqli_query something like this?

```
$res = mysqli_query($q1);
$res2 = mysqli_query($q2);
$res3 = mysqli_query($q3);
```

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, `desc` is a MySQL reserved word

- **http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html**

and must be wrapped in backticks if you're going to decide on using it, without renaming it to something else than `desc`, say `description` for instance.

Therefore, you will need to change it to the following, assuming your DB connection is established, and using `$con` as an example, which you haven't shown us what your DB connection is.

```
$q1 = "INSERT INTO t1 (id,`desc`) VALUES (1,'desc')";
$q2 = "SET @last_id = LAST_INSERT_ID()";
$q3 = "INSERT INTO t2 (parentid,`desc`) VALUES (@last_id, 'somedesc')";
```

minus all of your `<br>` tags, since you are inside PHP, unless that wasn't part of your code, but in trying to format your code in your question.

Sidenote: Your semi-colons were misplaced.

and passing DB connection to your queries:

```
$res = mysqli_query($con,$q1);
$res2 = mysqli_query($con,$q2);
$res3 = mysqli_query($con,$q3);
```

Plus, adding `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()` to check for possible errors in your queries.